# List of identities I can pretend via sudo -u

Tags: linux, bash, authentication, command-line

Goodmorning everybody!

I am asking this question today because I don't find it on the web, and if it was so obvious, please don't beat me!

I can connect on several machines via my own user, but on some machine, I have the ability to do a `sudo -u XXXX -i` to be logged as another user. This gives me the ability to manage an application, or stuff like that. I can't however do `sudo su`.

What I would like to know is how to have a list of all the identities I can pretend to be via this command (all the `XXXX` values that will be valid and accepted).

Thanks a lot for your answer!

Best regards,

Comment: I doubt it is possible to generate a list, since the basic information required is not readable for your normal account, typically. Also there are more options than just user accounts, a system administrator might also grant the execution of specific commands under some user account for you but keep a general account access blocked. So the resulting option set is quite complex.

Comment: We, actually there is one simple approach you can attempt: since you can access the list of local user accounts (`cat /etc/passwd`), you can simply make a brute force attempt and try all accounts. That certainly will succeed and allow you to put together a list. But it will also be regarded as aggressive behavior and reported to the system administrator. So maybe it is better to simply ask for the list :-)

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon everybody!

I finally found out what was the command I was looking for (it was quite simple in fact).

With `sudo -l` I can get the identities I can pretend via `sudo -u`.

Here is an output sample:

```
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for sexyuser on this host:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME
    HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME
    LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION
    LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC
    LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS
    _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User sexyuser may run the following commands on this host:
    (root) PASSWD: ALL
    (oracle) PASSWD: ALL
    (svn) PASSWD: ALL
```

Thanks again for your help!

Best regards.